# Will a single derivation of an abstract interface have it's virtual functions inlined?

Tags: c++

I have a pure virtual base class as an interface

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

I have 2 derivations of this interface, 1 for production use and 1 for test use

```
struct Production : Interface
{
    void foo() override;
};

struct Test : Interface
{
    void foo() override;
};
```

In my codebase I use `Interface` everywhere

```
void bar(Interface& i)
{
    i.foo();
}
```

However, in my production binary, **there is only a single derivation of `Interface`**, namely `Production`.

When compiling my production binary, will the compiler/linker/optimiser see that for every call to `Interface::foo()`, it is actually a call to `Production::foo()`, and inline the virtual function calls?

If so, does it matter if I'm compiling these in different static libraries? ie: The static library only sees `Interface`, but when linking, the linker knows it's a `Production`.

I'm currently using `gcc-4.9.2`

Comment: I would imagine this largely depends on the compiler

Comment: Isn't this a compiler specific question as well? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @EdHeal I've updated the question - I'm currently using gcc-4.9.2

Comment: @mwm314 I've updated the question - I'm currently using gcc-4.9.2

Comment: There's really only one way to find out the answer. Give us some output from objdump...that'll tell you.

Comment: Definitely not unless you have whole program optimization (LTO) enabled.  If so, then maybe :-) This is because the compiler when looking at a single translation unit cannot tell what derived types might be defined in other translation units.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unlikely with gcc. You could help some better luck with CLang - but I am saying this based on their sales pitch, not any real facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the only way to know in this *specific* case is to look at the code that's generated to find out.

That said, g++ 4.9 added a `-fdevirtualize` switch that's intended to do exactly this, at least under the right circumstances (and I've tested it and found cases where it definitely did work).

It was implemented in g++ by Honza Hubička, who wrote some about it in his blog:

http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html
http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-2-low-level.html
http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-3-building.html
http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/02/devirtualization-in-c-part-4-analyzing.html

If you read these, you'll see why Crazy Eddie (for one example) was skeptical about anybody doing this--although it's been done, and does work, implementation is *clearly* non-trivial.

As far as writing your code goes: since you don't expect any runtime polymorphism anyway, you might consider using a template-based solution instead.

```
struct Production 
{
    void foo();
};

struct Test
{
    void foo();
};

template <class Interface>
void bar(Interface& i)
{
    i.foo();
}
```

Of course, in most cases, you end up with the `Interface` as a parameter to a class template, not a function template, but the basic idea remains the same--you define your `Test` and `Production` versions with the same interface (but *not* using a base class or virtual functions), and then instantiate over the `Test` version when testing and the `Production` version for production code. This, of course, works with essentially any compiler all the time, not just the right compiler under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

There's no accurate answer to this question except: *maybe*.

I would seriously doubt anyone's bothered to develop the matching for this optimization.  It would have to be a "whole program optimization" or "link time optimization" for one.  Most people don't build with that turned on.

Further it could be voided out if the library is not static.  Meaning even abi-compatible library changes could affect the validity of the optimization.  `unique_ptr<Interface> fun()` could suddenly start returning different derived classes based on some internal state of the library.

So my answer, and again it's not correct, is: I seriously doubt any compiler does this.